# AWS Lightsail: cannot connect to FreeBSD instance created from snapshot

Tags: freebsd, amazon

I have an amazon Lightsail instance running FreeBSD. As I initially chose the lowest performance instance, I wanted to upgrade and thought this would be easy: just create a snapshot and create a new instance from this snapshot.

That's what I did and it worked so far. Only there is no way I can connect to this instance. I tried the SSH console in the AWS webpage, I tried to connect via SSH from my computer, using the new IP address. I even tried with the static IP address I had used on my old instance (and had transferred to the new one for the sake of testing). Of course I tried stopping the instance and restarting it several times.

There are no error messages when trying to connect, only nothing happens until it at some point times out.

I can't say for sure that it's not a setting on the server that prevents this, but at the moment I'm clueless about what that could be.

Fortunately, the old instance is still running and well. But this creeps me out: I'm doing daily snapshots, which as it seems are completely useless, as I cannot create an accessible instance from them.

What's the cause for this problem? Could it have to do with FreeBSD as an operating system of the instance? Is there anything else I could try?

I also compared the informations of the instances I got from `aws lightsail get-instances` and did not find anything suspicious. Is there anything in particular I could look for?

Comment: I just tried it with a completely newly created instance with FreeBSD as OS: created the instance, connection possible. Created a snapshot, created a new instance from the snapshot: connection impossible (even from the web ssh). So it seems to be an AWS problem, not anything I configured wrong. Time to move to another service...